# How to pass a cookie with Axios Post Request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, npm, axios

There is no cookie being passed with my request, been looking around and tried withCredentials, etc.

This is the latest code I have up, anyone know what I am missing here?

```
var cookie_for_data = "token=test";
    var host = "http://localhost:3000/"
axios.post(host + 'save_profile', {

                data: {
                    first_name: user_data["first_name"],
                    last_name: user_data["last_name"]
                    
                },
                headers: {
                    Cookie: cookie_for_data
                }

            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log("response", response.data);
                createUserPref(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("create user api error:", error);
            });
```

Comment: localhost can't own cookies, try another host.

Comment: Not true, I send cookies with postman to localhost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
var cookie_for_data = "token=test";
      var host = "http://localhost:3000/";
      axios
        .post(
          host + "save_profile",
          {
            first_name: user_data["first_name"],
            last_name: user_data["last_name"],
          },
          {
            headers: {
              Cookie: cookie_for_data,
            },
          }
        )
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("response", response.data);
          createUserPref(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("create user api error:", error);
        });
```

Comment: This is giving me "Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie""

Comment: I have not had this problem, but 2 things you can try:
   1. add a withCredentials: true to the axios option
   2. instead of  ```var cookie_for_data = ""```, try ```document.cookie = ""```, and then headers.Cookie would be document.cookie.